# Unsupervised Clustering using K-Modes

Tags: machine-learning

I have to find the effective time and day to send emails to the doctors.

We have doctors belonging to a specific hospital ....also we have the date/time when they opened the mail . But certain doctors have not opened the mail and we observed that the mail sent timing is not proper.

So I decided to use the following steps:

1. I have identified the doctors in a hospital who opened the mail earlier, so I could recommend the same timing and day to other doctors in the same hospital who hasn't opened the mail yet.
2. The problem with this approach is I have huge number of hospital details in the list , so clustering based on hospitals using k-modes seems not correct and appropriate.

How to proceed further? The ultimate goal is to prescribe the desired time and day to  sales rep while sending mails to the doctors.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your goal is to recommend ideal time to salesrep to send email, you should ideally go for Time series analysis like Number of mails checked by doctors on an hourly basis.